# How to do change of variables in multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I came across this problem from an exam about recursive estimation I found online:

Let $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
     $x\in\R^n$ and $y\in\R^n$ with a joint Gaussian distribution,

$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\mathcal{N}$ $\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \mu_x\\
                                                           \mu_y\\
                                                           \end{bmatrix}\
,\begin{bmatrix}\sum_x & \sum_{xy} \\
            \sum_{xy}^T & \sum_y \\ 
             \end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix} $

Find the variance of z = x - y

I couldn't find a change of variable formula for multivariate gaussian distributions online and I really don't know how to possibly solve this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The strategy is$$\operatorname{Var}(x-y)=\operatorname{Var}x+\operatorname{Var}y-2\operatorname{Cov}(x,\,y),$$but are you sure of the expression for your covariance matrix?

Comment: Hi @J.G. thanks for your response. I edited the covariance matrix, it was indeed wrong. I will try your strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets rewrite your variables,
$$
q = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\\end{bmatrix}\\
\mu = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_x\\ \mu_y\\\end{bmatrix}\\
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{xx} & \Sigma_{xy}\\ \Sigma_{yx} & \Sigma_{xy} \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then what you are referring to is an affine transformation
$$
{z} = B q\\
B = \begin{bmatrix} {I} & -{I}\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation:%7E:text=.-,Affine%20transformation,-%5Bedit%5D), after an affine transformation, $z$ will be distributed according to a normal distribution
$$
z \sim N\left( B\mu, B \Sigma B^T \right).
$$